# Operator +/- overloading as a non member function in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

So I have written some code that implements this hierarchy:

```
class A 
{
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    A ()  { }
    void setX(int x) { this->x = x;}
    void setY(int y) { this->y = y;}    
    int getX(void) { return x;}
    int getY(void) { return y;}    
    virtual int somefunc() = 0;
    friend B operator- ( B b1, B b2);
};    

class B : public A
{
    int somefunc() {return 0;}
};

class C : public A
{
    int somefunc() {return 1;}  
};

class D : public C
{
    int somefunc() {return 2;}
};
/*
// 1 st attempt - fail
A operator- (const A& a_inst, const A& a_inst2)
{
    A a_temp; 
    a_temp.setX( a_inst.getX() - a_inst2.getX() );
    a_temp.setY( a_inst.getY() - a_inst2.getY() );    
    return a_temp;  
}

// 2nd attempt - FAIL
const A* operator- (const A* a1, const A* a2)
{
    a1.setX( a1.getX() - a2.getX() );
    a1.setY( a1.getY() - a2.getY() );
    return a1;
}
//*/


//3rd  attempt
B operator- ( B b1, B b2)
{
    int temp1x =  b1.getX();
    int temp2x = b2.getX();
    b1.setX( temp1x - temp2x );

    int temp1y =  b1.getY();
    int temp2y = b2.getY();
    b2.setY( temp1y - temp2y );
    return b1;
}



 int main()
{
    B b();
    C c();

    b = b - dynamic_cast<B*>(c) ;
}
```

I understand that since A is an abstract class it can't be instantiated, so I can't do it with Class A instances.

Is it possible to overload both +/- once (each) and make it apply for every instance that belongs to a class in this hierarchy? Also I want to point out that I want to be able to do the same thing with objects of different classes at the same time like so:

```
C c;
B b;
b = b - c;
```

EDIT 1~ added a second version of the overloading that I am currently trying to get to work.

EDIT 2~ Corrected mistaken call of setters

EDIT 3~ added a 3rd version, still getting errors

Comment: Do you know what type your results should be?  Does `D - D` produce a `D`?  Would `B - D` be legal?  If so, what would resulting type be?

Comment: @DrewDormann I suppose it would be legal. What I am trying to do is add/subtract the x and y values (every class in this hierarchy has them). This applies regardless of the classes' (that are involved) type. (RE-EDITed)

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't implement this as a member function of A?

Comment: Do you understand what I'm asking?  What would be the type of `B - D`?  If you're not sure what you want, that's why you're having trouble writing it.

Comment: Not possible if abstract since you want to return a full instance of `A`. Split it into some classes `A0` and `A1`.

Comment: @remyabel No problem, yeah this was the initial approach. But my question remains. Is there a way to overload these operators once, so that I can use them with mixed type objects (that belong to this hierarchy)?.

Comment: @Mechanic: Not easily, it's best to simply write all the combinations if possible.  If you have a lot of combinations, we can show you the magic to make it work, but you'd probably have to copy-paste it without understanding.

Comment: @MooingDuck Firstly, Thanks. Although would you care to elaborate on "it's best to simply write all the combinations if possible " ? or provide an answer even?

Comment: @MooingDuck Shouldn't this version be working?

Comment: @Mechanic: At the absolute minimum, `a_temp.setX()`, `setX` requires an argument...

Comment: @Mechanic: I just altered your question to be clearer, I didn't "fix" broken code any more than necessary so that the question makes sense.  I trimmed it down to essentials.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes I understood that, I was asking about my edits right after that though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems in you code:
1. You should specify the inheritance type: public

```
class B : public A {
    ...
}
```

2. B operator- (const B& a_inst, const B& a_inst2)

```
{
    B a_temp; 
    a_temp.setX() = a.getX() - a_inst2.getX();
    a_temp.setY() = a.getY() - a_inst2.getY();

    return a_temp;  
}
```

You can't use like that, since setX and setY returns value not pointer or reference.